# Need a Negative to Positive Level Shifter

Tags: 3.3v

I did a simple differantial amplifer for 0-3.3V output. But, as you see I got -3.3V output because gain. I need a shifter circuitry for non-negative output. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Try connecting the grounded terminal of R4 to +1.65 V instead of ground.

Comment: thanks but I need a shifter circuit for output of op amp. Also I connected R4 +1.65V instead of ground but it did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? What result were you expecting and how was the actual result different? Because the circuit you shared should not produce a negative output with the given inputs.

Comment: If you actually do get a negative output with those inputs, you might need to share the power supply voltages and the load for us to be able to see why.

Comment: Do you want inverting gain=-1 > Vref =1.65 to output 3.3 to 0 from 0 to 3.3Vin? or actually 0 to 10V in and 3.3 to 0 out? or what. A level shifter is for logic.  Offset or Vref  is for Analog.  So define gain = 1/3? and offset=?

Comment: if BAT1 = 10V and BAT2 = 0V then I got -3.3V. I just wanna convert -3.3V to 3.3V without absolute circuit.

Comment: inputs are in that picture gave me +1.65V. there is no wrong. I just forgot change inputs when screenshot

Comment: If you want to invert the gain, you could just swap your inputs instead of adding a second stage.